# Binding multiple checkboxes of children to one parent

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-component

Is there's any way to bind multiple checkboxes from many children to one parent (f.e. via model)?

Let's say that the child component has something like:

```
<input
  type="checkbox"
  :id="'ticket-'+id"
  :checked="checked"
/>
```

Now, is it possible to have a parent prop like `selected` that would collect the id as values in an array of all checked checkboxes from children?

```
{
  selected: [
    5,
    8
  ]
}
```

The nearest thing to my solution in mind is [this](https://www.davidebarranca.com/2016/08/vue-js-binding-a-component-in-a-v-for-loop-to-the-parent-model/). But in my case, I don't want to keep track of unchecked instances.

Comment: You can listen to `change` event on parent container and update the model if the even target is checked.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia Could you provide some basic code implementation of the solution that's on your mind, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the checkbox `change` events on the parent and call a method which updates the data model.

Check out the fiddle below demonstrating this. (Go full page to see it properly)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    list: [
    { id: 1, label: 'Check 1'},
    { id: 2, label: 'Check 2'},
    { id: 3, label: 'Check 3'},
    { id: 4, label: 'Check 4'},
    ],
    selected: []
  },
  methods: {
    handleChange: function(ev) {
      let id = ev.target.id;
        if (ev.target.checked) {
        if (!this.selected.includes(id)) {
            this.selected.push(id);
        }
      } else {
        this.selected = this.selected.filter(function (item) {
            return item !== id;
        });
      }
      
      console.log('Updated: ', this.selected);
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <ol @change="handleChange">
    <li v-for="check in list">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" :id="check.id" />
        <span>{{check.label}}</span>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great but in my case, the checkboxes are inside child components and the array of selected records I want to track should be in the parent component and that's the tricky part. 

How to bind multiple checkboxes from multiple children to a single parent?

Comment: You can use `$emit()` from child components with the id if selected and listen that on parent where you can then update the status.